# Silhouette function for agglomerative hierarchic clustering validation

Tags: hierarchical-clustering

How to make a silhouette validation on Agglomerative Hierarchical Clustering? I want to look the quality of my cluster.
Thanks...
Zhayn

Comment: can you be a bit more specific? What programming language are you doing it in and do you have an example?

Comment: I want to use R software. I need the silhouette function to validate my cluster